# Can you use annotations for any use-case of Web.xml in Java EE?

Tags: java-ee, tomcat, annotations

Nowadays I have been practising **Java EE**. There are may annotations which simplify configuration of servlet container. Such as:

- @WebServlet
- @WebInitParam
- @ServletSecurity
- etc.

You can do the same thing in deployment descriptor: `Web.xml` Personally, I prefer annotations.

My questions are:

- can I use annotations for any possible use-case of the Web.xml?
- Any existing limitations, except that Java EE specific version needs to support annotations?

Best regards

Answer (score 2):

> Any existing limitations, except that Java EE specific version needs to support annotations?

One thing I know of is *ordering*.

From the [Servlet 3.1 specs](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html):

> The order in which the Listeners, Servlets are loaded from the various framework jars / classes in the WEB-INF/classes or WEB-INF/lib is unspecified when using annotations. If ordering is important then look at the section for modularity of web.xml and ordering of web.xml and web-fragment.xml below. The order can be specified in the deployment descriptor only.

As for your first point:

> can I use annotations for any possible use-case of the Web.xml?

Apart from that limitation, yes (I'm not aware of others, but there might be more). But even then people will try workarounds and still use annotations because they prefer that style.